# "namespace is not included in the assembly" issue

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm modifing demo application from this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

I just coppied DemoApp project into my solution. Now I can not load xaml files, such errors are reported:

> Error 5   Undefined CLR namespace. The 'clr-namespace' URI refers to a
>   namespace 'DemoApp.ViewModel' that is not included in the
>   assembly. C:\Oleg\projects\MySln\TerminatorConsole2\MainWindow.xaml   5   12  TerminatorConsole2
>   Error 2   Undefined CLR namespace. The 'clr-namespace' URI refers to a
>   namespace 'DemoApp.View' that is not included in the
>   assembly. C:\Oleg\projects\MySln\TerminatorConsole2\MainWindowResources.xaml  8   12  TerminatorConsole2

Probably just copying project folder is not enough? May be solution file contains some "project specific" information?

How to solve my problem?

**upd**: also I renamed "DemoApp" project folder on file system to "TerminatorConsole2"

**upd2**: well the question is probably what and where VS expects to find???

**upd3** During runtime I receive such exception, I think this is somehow connected:

```
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Oleg\projects\My.MBClient\TerminatorConsole2\bin\Release\TerminatorConsole2.vshost.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Oleg/projects/My.MBClient/TerminatorConsole2/bin/Release/My.MBClient.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Oleg/projects/My.MBClient/TerminatorConsole2/bin/Release/My.MBClient/My.MBClient.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Oleg/projects/My.MBClient/TerminatorConsole2/bin/Release/My.MBClient.EXE.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing terminated.

  StackTrace:
       at TerminatorConsole2.Utils.WcfLoader..ctor(WcfModel model)
       at TerminatorConsole2.ViewModel.MainWindowViewModel.ShowAllStrategies() in C:\Oleg\projects\My.MBClient\TerminatorConsole2\ViewModel\MainWindowViewModel.cs:line 106
       at TerminatorConsole2.ViewModel.MainWindowViewModel.<CreateCommands>b__1(Object param) in C:\Oleg\projects\My.MBClient\TerminatorConsole2\ViewModel\MainWindowViewModel.cs:line 54
       at TerminatorConsole2.RelayCommand.Execute(Object parameter) in C:\Oleg\projects\My.MBClient\TerminatorConsole2\RelayCommand.cs:line 67
       at MS.Internal.Commands.CommandHelpers.CriticalExecuteCommandSource(ICommandSource commandSource, Boolean userInitiated)
       at System.Windows.Documents.Hyperlink.OnClick()
```

I don't have such files on my computer, why VS is looking for them?

```
file:///C:/Oleg/projects/My.MBClient/TerminatorConsole2/bin/Release/My.MBClient.DLL.
file:///C:/Oleg/projects/My.MBClient/TerminatorConsole2/bin/Release/My.MBClient/My.MBClient.DLL.
```

Comment: I downloaded the C# code for your tutorial from [HERE](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mag200902MVVM/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=2026). Extracted and ran it. It worked just fine. Are you adding the extracted folder to some other solution

Comment: Way too little information. Post the XAML (header and actual line) and the main project structure.

Comment: Open Solution Explorer and watch out for assemblies with exclamation mark. These are the missing one's.

Comment: that's correct. i'm adding `DemoApp` project to my own solution. I don't use shiped *.sln files and unit tests

Comment: I see such highlighted errors. `xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:DemoApp.ViewModel"` however I don't understand why VS can't find this namespace, it exist in project, I only renamed "DemoApp" folder to "TerminatorConsole2" folder. I've renamed folder on file system, I didn't renamed namespaces!

Comment: Do you have a missing reference?  If you created your own solution then project references within the solution may have been lost.

Comment: Well, VS is looking for a namespace called `DemoApp.View` (case sensitive and *not* nested inside another namespace) that exists within the same assembly as the Xaml.

Comment: @DanPuzey i've updated description, for some reason VS is looking for some DLL's I don't have...

Answer (score 1):

In "Configuration Manager" i've changed target platform to "x86" from "AnyCPU", it seems I use somehow other projects that "x86" targeted and this things cannot be mixed. after that problems gone

Answer (score 0):

Open **.xaml files** in **XAML View Mode**,

Look at the similiar code

```
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:DemoApp.ViewModel"
```

and correct **DemoApp.ViewModel** to your own.

I guess, You should change it to **TerminatorConsole2**

Comment: what is my own? I didn't changed namespaces. why 'DemoApp.View' is not included in the assembly, i didn't changed assembly files?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than just copying the two folders, I would suggest you to take this route.

1) Right-click on the solution and select add existing projects. Then move to the DemoApp directory and click on *.csproj file. This will add DemoApp to your solution

2) Similarly add unittest project

3) Right click on the DemoApp in Solution explorer and set it as startup project

Comment: i copied `DemoApp` folder content to created by me `TerminatorConsole2` folder in my solution, then i did 1) using my `TerminatorConsole2` just created project. I don't need unit tests

Comment: you just remove the DemoApp folder now and add it as an existing project. Then set it as startup project, it will surely work

Comment: But I don't want "DemoApp" folder in my file system. Ok I will try to rename "DemoApp" project in VS Solution Explorer, probably it will update folder name as well

Comment: No, it doesn't matter how the project is named, I stil have "DemoApp" folder

Comment: I am not able to uderstand what actually you looking for. Changing the name of DemoApp won't help, it will create a mess. Just add it as an another project to your solution, whats the harm in that

Comment: If you are just copying the content i.e files and other folders from it then you will need to change the namespaces in all the files. Namespace are defined at top of .cs files.